# Is there option to auto terminate Azure SQL DW

Tags: azure, terminate, azure-synapse

I am using Azure SQL DW which costs more per an hour. So I want to know is there option for auto terminate SQL DW after an hour or so?

Answer (score 3):

You can pause the Azure Data warehouse and then you only pay for the storage used.
You can automate pausing your DWH by using an Azure automation account and a runbook. 
This blog explains the process:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/allanmiller/2017/09/20/pausing-azure-sql-data-warehouse-using-an-automation-runbook/

Markus

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

To save costs, you can pause and resume compute resources on-demand. For example, if you won't be using the database during the night and on weekends, you can pause it during those times, and resume it during the day. You won't be charged for DWUs while the database is paused.

When you pause a database:

Compute and memory resources are returned to the pool of available resources in the data center

- DWU costs are zero for the duration of the pause.
- Data storage is not affected and your data stays intact.
- SQL Data Warehouse cancels all running or queued operations.

To pause a database, use the [Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/suspend-azurermsqldatabase?view=azurermps-5.1.1).

```
Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase –ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup1" `
–ServerName "Server01" –DatabaseName "Database02"
```

To start a database, use the [Resume-AzureRmSqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/resume-azurermsqldatabase?view=azurermps-5.1.1) cmdlet.

```
Resume-AzureRmSqlDatabase –ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup1" `
–ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database02"
```

More information please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-compute-powershell).

As Markus Bohse said, you also could use Automation to do this.

[image]

Note: You also could write a runbook to start your database.

Update: If you want to use java to do this, please refer to this [API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.sql._sql_warehouse.pausedatawarehouse).

```
public void pauseDataWarehouse()
```

Update:

You also could Rest API to do this. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-compute-rest-api)

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{server-name}/databases/{database-name}/pause?api-version=2014-04-01-preview HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: I want to terminate SQL DW at certain time. Is there any options for it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You could set a schedule on your runbook. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-schedules

Comment: You also could use Azure CLi 2.0 to pause SQL DW. Please refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/dw?view=azure-cli-latest#az_sql_dw_pause

Comment: @karan I find a good [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-sql/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/sql/SqlServerOperationsTests.java#L369) for your scenario. Maybe you could try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use runbooks or powershell script to pause dn resume SQL DWH.

Powershell script is below. If you would like "runbook" let me know

---

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName='None')]
Param 
(    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    [String] 
    $AzureSubscriptionId, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    [String] 
    $AzureDataWareHouseList="All", 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet("Suspend","Resume")] 
    [String] 
    $Action 
)

function PauseAzureDWH
{
    Param
    (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    [String] 
    $AzureSubscriptionId, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    [String] 
    $AzureDataWareHouseList="All", 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet("Suspend","Resume")] 
    [String] 
    $Action
    )
    try     
    {

    Login-AzureRmAccount
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $AzureSubscriptionId 

    if($AzureDataWareHouseList -ne "All") 
    {
        $AzureDWHList = @()
        $AzureDWHTotalList = $AzureDataWareHouseList.Split(",") 
        foreach($DWHitem in $AzureDWHTotalList)
        {
            $DWH = "*$DWHitem*"
            $DWH = Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object ResourceName -like $DWH
            if($DWH -ne $Null)
            {
                $dwc = $DWH.ResourceName.split("/")
                # splat reused parameter lists
                $ThisDW = @{
                'ResourceGroupName' = $DWH.ResourceGroupName
                'ServerName' = $dwc[0]
                'DatabaseName' = $dwc[1]
                }
                $AzureDWHList += $ThisDW
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Warning "Given DataWarehouse '$DWHitem' is not found in given subscription"
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        [array]$TotalDataWareHouseList = Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object ResourceType -EQ "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases" | Where-Object Kind -Like "*datawarehouse*"
        $AzureDWHList = @()
        foreach($DWH in $TotalDataWareHouseList)
        {
            $dwc = $DWH.ResourceName.split("/")
            $ThisDW = @{
            'ResourceGroupName' = $DWH.ResourceGroupName
            'ServerName' = $dwc[0]
            'DatabaseName' = $dwc[1]
            }
            $AzureDWHList += $ThisDW
        }
    }

    <# foreach($AzureDWHItem in $AzureDWHList) 
    {
        if(!(Get-AzureRmResource | ? {$_.Name -eq $AzureDWHItem.ServerName}) ) 
        {
            throw " AzureDWH : [$AzureDWHItem] - Does not exist! - please Check your inputs " 
        }
    } #>

    if($Action -eq "Suspend") 
    {
        Write-Output "Suspending Azure DataWareHouses"; 
        foreach ($AzureDWH in $AzureDWHList) 
        { 
            $status = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase @AzureDWH | Select Status
            if($status.Status -eq "Online")
            {
                Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase @AzureDWH
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    { 
        Write-Output "Resuming Azure DataWareHouses"; 
        foreach ($AzureDWH in $AzureDWHList) 
        {
            $status = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase @AzureDWH | Select Status
            if($status.Status -eq "Paused")
            {
                Resume-AzureRmSqlDatabase @AzureDWH
            }
        }
    }
}

catch
{
    Write-Error " Exception while getting resource details and writing back to CSV"
    Write-Error $_.Exception.message
    Write-Error " ErrorStack: $Error[0] "
    exit 1

}
}

PauseAzureDWH -AzureSubscriptionId $AzureSubscriptionId -AzureDataWareHouseList $AzureDataWareHouseList -Action $Action
```

---